# How to get the number of columns in the given row in Excel sheet with C#?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am using  C# Interop Excel and I have a Excel sheet with the column names in the first row and some data below it. So I want to get the number of the column names which means the number of columns in the first row.

I have tried something like that but it returns incorrect value:

```
int colCount = ((Excel.Range)xlWorkSheet.Rows[1]).EntireRow.Columns.Count;
```

Any idea how can I get the first row as a range and then get count of the columns in this range?

Comment: In Excel you would do it as such: `colCount = Sheet1.Cells(1, Sheet1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ...

```
var xlApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
var xlWorkbook = xlApplication.Workbooks.Open("YourWorkbook.xlsx");
var xlWorksheets = xlWorkbook.Worksheets;
var xlWorksheet = xlWorksheets[1] as Worksheet;

var columnCount = xlWorksheet.Columns.Count;
```

... or based on what you're asking, for the last column in a row based on usage (the example is for row 1, loop if you need to or specify a particular row of your choice) ...

```
var columnCount = xlWorksheet.Cells[1, xlWorksheet.Columns.Count].End[XlDirection.xlToLeft].Column;
```

Comment: it is exactly what I was looking for, Thanks a lot! I did not want to use simply xlWorksheet.Columns.Count, because if any row contains more columns than headers then they are invalid data and I wanted to ignore them.

Comment: @cj__ no worries man. Just do me a favor and mark it as the answer. L